# How to display the same star system in ma web page which I created in backend

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have created a 5 star rating system plugin using jQuery in wordpress (backend). The star values are also getting updated in to post meta table. How to display the same star system in ma page. Here's my plugin code.

```
<?php

/* Plugin Name: Star Rating
 * Version: 1.0
 */

class starrating{

    public function __construct(){
    add_action('add_meta_boxes',array($this,'my_meta'));
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts',array($this ,'starscript' ));
    add_action('save_post', array($this,'save_field'));
    }


    public function my_meta()

    {

        add_meta_box(
       'my_custom_meta',
       'Created By',
        array($this,'my_meta_box_mes'),
       'a_z',
       'side',
       'low'
    );

    }

    public function save_field($post_id)

    {
    update_post_meta($post_id,'starrating',$_POST['rating']);    
 }


    public function my_meta_box_mes()
    {

    ?>
     <label>Please Rate Your Ratings !!</label>
     <p>
  <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating" />
<ul class="rating" onMouseOut="resetRating();">
  <li name="star" value="one" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="two" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="three" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="four" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
  <li name="star" value="five" onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onclick="addRating(this);">&#x2605;</li>
</ul>
    </p>



     <?php
    }
    public function starscript(){
     wp_enqueue_script( 'star_id',content_url() . '/plugins/star_rating/js/starrating.js' );
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery_id', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'styl_id',content_url() . '/plugins/star_rating/css/star.css' ); 

    }
}
$star=new starrating();

?>
```

Comment: Anyone with a helping hand ? ?

Comment: `get_post_meta`?

Comment: using get_post_meta am getting the rating given to the post in the backend. Now i want to use tht rating and want to display on my webpage

Comment: Too broad for a single answer... you gotta enqueue the scripts on the frontend, use a shortcode or widget to display the rating system, and use Ajax to save the values on the database... stars should be saved as an array so you can have multiple stars for each post.